# .NET Core3.0 ASP.NET Web AP gets 404 on controller actionsonly when deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have all aspnetcore movdulev2, all necessary software instaled on the server. IIS recognizes the web site and I put a default page that shows up. THe only probelem is when I hot the controller/action from the root application path of the webAPi app I get 404. I have tried different formats of routing, including a default .Net core 3 app from Microsoft. Everything works on my local IIS Express but not on IIS. App pool is .NttCore NoManaged Apppool. I do not have any permission issues.
My *program .cs* & Web.config are below:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    
                });
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" verb="*" 
        modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication2Test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
       stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If anyone can help provide direction that will help.

Comment: If it can run successfully on iis express, the problem has little to do with the startup code. It is not easy to judge where the problem lies only from your existing information. You can open the errorpage module of iis and set the error response to detailed error so that you can see more information about 404. At the same time, open the fail request tracing function, record the entire request information completely, and check which module the error is.

Comment: Thanks much Bruce. I enabled failed request tracing but no log files are being created there. Also 404 is already set to detailed error logs in the error module but getting a "Lock Voilation" error while trying to pipe that to a File.

Comment: I was able to get to FRT logs finally. I found that the UrlRoutingModule is changed to StaticFileHandler

Comment: I was able to get to FRT logs finally. I found that the UrlRoutingModule is changed to StaticFileHandler after a **Phycal Path AccessPerm 513** comes up. Detail as follows: 
Name:ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 
Precondition: integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0 

PhysicalPath
 AccessPerms 513 

Name: UrlRoutingModule-4.0 
Precondition: managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0 

HANDLER_CHANGED :
NewHandlerName: StaticFile 
NewHandlerModules:
StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule.   Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your frt log, the routing module responsible for asp.net did not work. The request should have entered the routing pipeline but went to the static file processing module of iis. iis looked up in the file system according to the url but did not find it, so a 404 was reported. . You can use the following configuration to force the routing module to work.

```
<system.webServer>
    .....
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    .....
</system.webServer>
```